# nodejs Why can't I use puppeteer-core?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to use `puppeteer-core` and `chrome-aws-lambda` so I can upload my function to aws lambda but I get an error when running my script locally, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the modules but I still get an error, this is my code

```
const chrome = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: chrome.args,
        executablePath: "/home/usern/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br",
        headless: chrome.headless,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

It gives me this error, im not sure what to do to fix it

```
(node:17811) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 1: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: ���m�����鹲o�b�Vb%�]!yb: not found
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 1: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: �6��d�11�l��L���: not found
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 1: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: cannot open c: No such file
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 1: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: i��D-mPL�-X�R: not found
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 1: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: U�#.: not found
/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: 2: /home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium-75.0.3765.0.br: Syntax error: ")" unexpected


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:342:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/home/connor/Desktop/serverless/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:331:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:394:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:172:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
(node:17811) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17811) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

`puppeteer-core` does not include a `chrome` installation unlike the `puppeteer` package.

If you wish to use `puppeteer` in Lambda, try using a Lambda layer that already provides `chrome` for you such as https://github.com/RafalWilinski/serverless-puppeteer-layers.